# running a methode in the background with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

i am trying to create a keep alive method for a session that runs as demon but not sure if i am doing  it right

```
def async_loop(f):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        loop.run_until_complete(f(*args, **kwargs))

    return decorated
```

```
class Session:
     def __init__(self):
        self.keep_alive_task()

    async def keep_alive(self):
        while True:
            keep_alive_message = {
                "janus": "keepalive",
            }
            response=self.send(keep_alive_message)
            print(response)
            await asyncio.sleep(30)

    @async_loop
    async def keep_alive_task(self):
        asyncio.create_task(self.keep_alive())
```

Note: i did not put the self.send method it's just a simple method that sends a message using python-requests module

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work as you expected? If not, what specific problem(s) does it have?

Comment: it runs one iteration of the loop then it stops

Comment: Do you get any errors? Perhaps a `RuntimeError` that you can't run an event loop when one is already running? Maybe you also get a `RuntimeWarning` that the task you create in `keep_alive_task` was never awaited?

Comment: no  i dont have any `RuntimeError`

Comment: i think that the task don't get the chance to run again since it' concurrent just not sure

Comment: How are you running the code? I tried using `Session()` but got `RuntimeError` when calling `create_task` because there was no loop running. If I do something to get a loop running, I get a `RuntimeError`that an event loop is already running`run_until_complete`.

Comment: i am running testing in python shell `session=Session()` it shows no runtime error it only execute the first iteration

Comment: What shell are you using? If I use `python`, I get a `RuntimeError` that no loop is running. If I use `python -m asyncio` I get a `RuntimeError` that the loop is already running, but the code appears to work.

Comment: i used `python3 -m asyncio` it does runtime error now but if you remove the decorator to fix the runtime error you will get the behavior i was talking about it runs only the first iteration

Comment: @dirn ty i think the problem was that task already start the corotine so i dont need the decorator

Comment: The problem is that you aren't running anything else in the event loop. Unless you do something that tells your code to wait until something completes, the event loop is only going to let your task run until it yields control back the first time. Given that nothing else in your code seems to use asyncio, you'd probably be better off using a background thread for your heartbeat.